# How can I prevent a hyperlink in my comment?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks, markdown

I just made a comment in Stack Overflow and made an example "yourdomain.com/yourpage.asp" which  was automatically converted into a hyperlink.

Unfortunately this hyperlink goes to some web hosting company that seems to have bought this domain.

I would like to prevent that. Can I?

How can I prevent "yourdomain.com/yourpage.asp" from becoming a hyperlink in my comment?

Comment: like this? `yourdomain.com/yourpage.asp`

Comment: Just wrap it in backticks. (As if you were posting code in a comment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative: Use `example.com` instead. It's a domain specifically set up *for this purpose*: being an example. So you don't have to worry about where you're actually linking.

To answer your question though, you can always enclose the link in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

URLs will only be hyperlinked if they include a scheme part. So `http://domain.com/foo` will by linked, but `domain.com/foo` will not.

Comment: It looks like comments are only processed as hyperlinks if they are valid hyperlinks. For instance, http://… will not get processed as a hyperlink. FWIW.